# Meteor.users is undefined

Tags: meteor

I got an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
```

when I run my application, and I discovered that the undefined thing mentioned before is "Meteor.users"

as it's used to insert some data to the database like so (that is the cause of the error):

```
  var tomId = Meteor.users.insert({username: "Tom",
    profile: { name: 'Tom Coleman', username:"Tom" }
  });
```

and I don't know how to make it work normally without being undefined

any help ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create new users. Please be specific what you are asking, otherwise it's difficult to solve your problem for others. If you are trying to create users there are several approaches

Comment: Have you installed the accounts package?

Comment: @MichelFloyd thank you , I downloaded the package and the error was gone

Comment: @mostafizrahman yes , I am trying to create a new user , still I couldn't do that because Meteor. users was undefined

Answer (score 1):

To create a new user in your application's users collection the easiest and safest way is to add `accounts-base` package first and then using it's API.

Add `accounts-base` by

```
meteor add accounts-base
```

Then what you need to do is:

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

//now create your user
Accounts.createUser({
      username: YOUR_USERNAME,
      email: EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      password: PASSWORD,
      profile: {
          // WHATEVER OBJECT
      }
});
```